# Slice a list into a nested list based on special characters using Python

Tags: python, windows

I have a list of strings like this:

```
lst = ['23532','user_name=app','content=123',
       '###########################',
       '54546','user_name=bee','content=998 hello','source=fb',
       '###########################',
       '12/22/2015']
```

I want a similar method like string.split('#') that can give me output like this:

```
[['23532','user_name=app','content='123'],
 ['54546','user_name=bee',content='998 hello','source=fb'],
 ['12/22/2015']]
```

but I know list has not split attribute. I cannot use `''.join(lst)` either because this list comes from part of a txt file I read in and my txt.file was too big, so it will throw an **memory error** to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-liner for this, but you can easily write a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to do what you want:

```
def sublists(lst):
    x = []
    for item in lst:
        if item == '###########################':     # or whatever condition you like
            if x:
                yield x
            x = []
        else:
            x.append(item)
    if x:
        yield x

new_list = list(sublists(old_list))
```

Comment: but if it's one # short this fails. Not a good solution in my opinion

Comment: @OwenHempel Obviously the condition in line 4 can be rewritten to whatever OP wants.

Comment: I would think there exists a better solution, like a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `.join()`, you can loop through the `list` and save the index of any string that contains `#` then loop again to slice the list:

```
lst = ['23532', 'user_name=app', 'content=123', '###########################' ,'54546','user_name=bee','content=998 hello','source=fb','###########################','12/22/2015']
idx = []
new_lst = []
for i,val in enumerate(lst):
    if '#' in val:
        idx.append(i)
j = 0
for x in idx:
    new_lst.append(lst[j:x])
    j = x+1
new_lst.append(lst[j:])
print new_lst
```

output:

```
[['23532', 'user_name=app', 'content=123'], ['54546', 'user_name=bee', 'content=998 hello', 'source=fb'], ['12/22/2015']]
```

Comment: Instead of using `for i in range(len(lst))` you should use `for idx,val in enumerate(lst)` instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

```
sep = '###########################'

def split_list(_list):
    global sep
    lists = list()
    sub_list = list()
    for x in _list:
        if x == sep:
            lists.append(sub_list)
            sub_list = list()
        else:
            sub_list.append(x)
    lists.append(sub_list)
    return lists

l = ['23532','user_name=app','content=123',
     '###########################',
     '54546','user_name=bee','content=998 hello','source=fb',
     '###########################',
     '12/22/2015']

pprint(split_list(l))
```

Output:

```
[['23532', 'user_name=app', 'content=123'],
 ['54546', 'user_name=bee', 'content=998 hello', 'source=fb'],
 ['12/22/2015']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = ['23532','user_name=app','content=123',
     '###########################','54546','user_name=bee','content=998 hello','source=fb',
     '###########################','12/22/2015'] 

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x == '###########################')  if not k ]
```

Output

```
[['23532', 'user_name=app', 'content=123'],
 ['54546', 'user_name=bee', 'content=998 hello', 'source=fb'],
 ['12/22/2015']]
```